# Query amazon ec2 attributes from inside instance for checking pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, price

Amazon EC2 pricing api provides different attributes for each type of pricing, how am i able to know under which pricing my ec2 instance is running. Because in pricing api i.e. json file, amazon provides few attributes and out of these attributes i am only able to fetch instanceType from inside of an instance. how to get others?

```
[
    {
        "TDVRYW6K68T4XJHJ.JRTCKXETXF": {
            "effectiveDate": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z", 
            "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF", 
            "priceDimensions": {
                "TDVRYW6K68T4XJHJ.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                    "appliesTo": [], 
                    "beginRange": "0", 
                    "description": "$4.900 per On Demand Linux hs1.8xlarge Instance Hour", 
                    "endRange": "Inf", 
                    "pricePerUnit": {
                        "USD": "4.9000000000"
                    }, 
                    "rateCode": "TDVRYW6K68T4XJHJ.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7", 
                    "unit": "Hrs"
                }
            }, 
            "sku": "TDVRYW6K68T4XJHJ", 
            "termAttributes": {}
        }, 
        "attributes": {
            "clockSpeed": "2 GHz", 
            "currentGeneration": "No", 
            "instanceFamily": "Storage optimized", 
            "instanceType": "hs1.8xlarge", 
            "licenseModel": "No License required", 
            "location": "EU (Ireland)", 
            "locationType": "AWS Region", 
            "memory": "117 GiB", 
            "networkPerformance": "10 Gigabit", 
            "operatingSystem": "Linux", 
            "operation": "RunInstances", 
            "physicalProcessor": "Intel Xeon E5-2650", 
            "preInstalledSw": "NA", 
            "processorArchitecture": "64-bit", 
            "servicecode": "AmazonEC2", 
            "storage": "24 x 2000", 
            "tenancy": "Shared", 
            "usagetype": "EU-BoxUsage:hs1.8xlarge", 
            "vcpu": "17"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you please add more information as in what attributes you are looking for that differentiates the pricing. As I know, location is the only variable rest other information is derivable from the instance type.

Answer (score 0):

1) find your instance size and AZ.  For example

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-50-1-171 temp]$ ec2-metadata |grep placement
placement: eu-west-1a
[ec2-user@ip-10-50-1-171 temp]$ ec2-metadata |grep instance-type
instance-type: t2.micro
```

2) pull the correct file for the pricing of the EC2, for example at the moment it is
https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json

3) within this file there are "products".  So for instance within the products find a t2.micro for eu-west

```
"SYEPG42MVWFMUBT6" : {
  "sku" : "SYEPG42MVWFMUBT6",
  "productFamily" : "Compute Instance",
  "attributes" : {
    "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
    "location" : "EU (Ireland)",
    "locationType" : "AWS Region",
    "instanceType" : "t2.micro",
    "instanceFamily" : "General purpose",
    "vcpu" : "1",
    "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon Family",
    "clockSpeed" : "Up to 3.3 GHz",
    "memory" : "1 GiB",
    "storage" : "EBS only",
    "networkPerformance" : "Low to Moderate",
    "processorArchitecture" : "32-bit or 64-bit",
    "tenancy" : "Shared",
    "operatingSystem" : "SUSE",
    "licenseModel" : "No License required",
    "usagetype" : "EU-BoxUsage:t2.micro",
    "operation" : "RunInstances:000g",
    "preInstalledSw" : "NA",
    "processorFeatures" : "Intel AVX; Intel Turbo"
  }
},
```

Note the SKU for this product

4) next find the "terms" section in the json file.  There are sections for "OnDemand" and "Reserved".  In "OnDemand" the SKU for the product of interest (in the example above SYEPG42MVWFMUBT6) is mentioned once. In the "Reserved" there are several entries with different terms

If you need to do all these steps programmatically you'd have to use either a shell script and a tool like jq or a library for json processing like the one included with python

Comment: Yeah, I want to do it programatically, so, the issue is :- are we able to narrow down the result filtered from that json file to one sku using only these two details from ec2 instance?

Comment: Using a programming or scripting language of your choice, load the json and select the "product" using the AZ and the instance type.  This gives you a SKU.  Then use the SKU to lookup the appropriate "terms"

Comment: there is no where near enough info though - a t2.micro in the example here can be Amazon Linux, RHEL, SUSE, Windows, etc.

Comment: @thomas good point.  This is also an old old answer.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/paid-amis.html for some information on paid AMIs

Comment: To be honest I don’t think the answer has really changed. It is still not possible (at least even with a medium amount of effort) to use the pricing API to get the price for an instance. There simply isn’t enough info in the EC2 calls to filter the pricing API fully.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I know this question is old, and I **don't** have any definitive proof (someone please correct me if its wrong) But through experimenting I've found that to get *your specific running instance cost*, you really **cannot** use a combination of the EC2 Metadata and the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html API.</s>

This is because the information returned from the price API is for current offers available in the near term for instances *to be purchased* not your specific running instance.

Specifically what you would want to find is the Ratecode associated with your specific instance, and this is not found through calling [DescribeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html). You can apply a series of filters to get a pretty good guess, as to what the instance cost is likely for a specific instance running in your account. However, I am unable to uniquely define a specific instance even with some specific filters like the following

```js
{
                Filters: [
                    {
                        Type: 'TERM_MATCH',
                        Field: 'ServiceCode',
                        Value: 'AmazonEC2',
                    },
                    {
                        Type: 'TERM_MATCH',
                        Field: 'regionCode',
                        Value: 'us-east-1',
                    },
                    {
                        Type: 'TERM_MATCH',
                        Field: 'instanceType',
                        Value: 't3.medium',
                    },
                    {
                        Type: 'TERM_MATCH',
                        Field: 'marketoption',
                        Value: 'OnDemand',
                    },
                    {
                        Type: 'TERM_MATCH',
                        Field: 'operatingSystem',
                        Value: 'Linux',
                    },
                    {
                        Type: 'TERM_MATCH',
                        Field: 'tenancy',
                        Value: 'Shared',
                    },
                ],
                FormatVersion: 'aws_v1',
                NextToken: null,
                ServiceCode: 'AmazonEC2',
            };
```

(The above filter returns like ~50 different price offerings when used to query the [GetProductsAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_pricing_GetProducts.html) )

If its any help here is [some code I've been using to muck around](https://gist.github.com/twosdai/d265708e590b5d9b2ac7a382fbd5b651)

I haven't tested it but it might just be easier to Crawl the [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)

EDIT:
I worked with AWS support a bit and found a workable solution set of filters. Copying the response from AWS here:

I understand that you want to use aws price list query API to output the pricing of onDemand t3.medium instance, however it is throwing results for lot of instances of same instance type instead of getting output for the exact ec2 instance your queried for.

I was able to reproduce the same behavior from my end when I used the same filters you provided over an aws cli get-products request[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html). After digging into this a bit, I was able to substantially bring down the search result using the below filters with the help of a guide[2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_pricing_GetProducts.html).

Command:
`aws pricing get-products --filters file://filters2.json  --format-version aws_v1 --service-code AmazonEC2`

Filter json file:

```
[
  {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "ServiceCode",
                "Value": "AmazonEC2"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "regionCode",
                "Value": "us-east-1"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "instanceType",
                "Value": "t3.medium"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "marketoption",
                "Value": "OnDemand"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "operatingSystem",
                "Value": "Linux"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "tenancy",
                "Value": "Shared"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "preInstalledSw",
                "Value": "NA"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "licenseModel",
                "Value": "No License required"
        },
        {
                "Type": "TERM_MATCH",
                "Field": "capacitystatus",
                "Value": "Used"
        }
]
```

The following were the results in a nutshell:

1. On Demand Instance price for the instance matched in filter.
2. Reserved Instances:
   2.1: Term: 1 year or 3 year
   2.2: Upfront: none, partial or all
   2.3: Convertable: standard or convertable

I understand that you have applied a filter that matches key value 'marketoption:OnDemand', but in the output there is a seperate category called "terms" within "serviceCode" key. The terms then is then a nested array containing different keys for 'OnDemand' and 'Reserved' etc which would not be filtered by the above filters normally.

As for a workaround to filter out just the pricing of On Demand instance, I am afraid you would have to create custon json query to filter out only the values of the On demand instance returned from the output of the updated script.

Comment: Jokes on me it was easier to just crawl the pricing page.

Comment: Jokes on me again, its easier to reach out to support and ask questions.